# Row and column vector representation for Euclidian vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, notation

When dealing with Euclidean vector spaces (such as those in physics) we consider that a vector $A$ with a tuple of scalar components $(a,b,c)$ is equal to a vector $B$ with the same components, however, we make a distinction between column and row vectors (namely that one is the transpose of the other) is it that for a euclidean vector we just decide on one way of 'representation' and the distinction is more for dealing with matrices? Because this suggests that given a row vector $A$ and Column vector $B$ with the same components they are not equal. Is it a form of notation for vectors or are we essentially writing the components in a matrix?

If we define a vector $a=(a_1,a_2)$ as being represented as a column and row vector, then for $a$, $Ma≠Ma$ as one is defined and the other is not.

Comment: are we actually multiplying the euclidean vector to a matrix or instead forming a matrix (column vector with its components in the positions)?

Comment: Maybe you will find it reassuring to know that $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R^{m\times n}$ are only defined up to a natural isomorphism, i.e. questions like$$\text{"What is a tuple?"}$$or$$\text{"Does the set of tuples equal the set of column vectors?"}$$don't make sense. In case you are interested to know more about that, I can add another answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $n$ be a positive integer.

- A row vector with $n$ real components is a matrix with one row and $n$ columns, i.e. an element of $\mathbb R^{1\times n}$.
- A column vector with $n$ real components is a matrix with one column and $n$ rows, i.e. an element of $\mathbb R^{n\times 1}$.
- An element of $\mathbb R^n$ is a list of $n$ real numbers.

Of course we identify lists, row and column vectors through "obvious" bijections. For example, given a list$$(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb R^n$$ we can set $$\forall i:x_{i,1}:=x_i$$and $$\begin{pmatrix}x_{1,1}\\\vdots\\x_{n,1}\end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb R^{n\times 1}$$is the column vector associated to the list.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing notation and coordinate representation of vectors. That is, a vector space is an algebraic structure defined using four objects $(V, \mathbb{F}, \oplus ,\odot )$ where $(V, \oplus)$ is an Abelian group, $(\mathbb{F},+,\cdot )$ is a field and

$$
\odot :\mathbb{F}\times V\to V,\quad (\lambda ,\mathbf{v})\mapsto \lambda \odot \mathbf{v}
$$

is a function named scalar multiplication, such that the following conditions holds:

$$
\lambda \odot (\mathbf{v}\oplus \mathbf{w})=(\lambda \odot \mathbf{v})\oplus (\lambda \odot \mathbf{w}),\quad 1\odot \mathbf{v}=\mathbf{v},\quad 0\odot \mathbf{v}=\mathbf 0
\\(\lambda  +\mu)\odot \mathbf{v}=(\lambda  \odot \mathbf{v})\oplus (\mu \odot \mathbf{v}),\quad (\lambda \cdot \mu )\odot \mathbf{v}=\lambda \odot (\mu \odot \mathbf{v})
$$

If the vector space have finite dimension (say dimension $n$), then there exists some list of linear independent vectors $\mathbf{v}_1,\ldots ,\mathbf{v}_n$ such that for every $\mathbf{w}\in V$ there exists scalars $\lambda _j\in \mathbb{F}$ such that

$$
\mathbf{w}=(\lambda _1\odot \mathbf{v}_1)\oplus \ldots \oplus (\lambda _n\odot \mathbf{v}_n)
$$

Then, using the previous list as a basis of $V$ we can represent the vector $\mathbf{w}$ as $(\lambda _1,\ldots ,\lambda _n)$, that is, there is a bijective map $\phi :V\to \mathbb{F}^n$ such that to each vector in $V$ gives a coordinate representation $(\lambda _1,\ldots ,\lambda _n)$, what is an element of $\mathbb{F}^n$.

So, for any Euclidean space $V$ of dimension $n$ we directly use the coordinate representation given by elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Now, as a notation we can represent any element of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by the standard notation for $n$-tuples, that is $(\lambda _1,\ldots ,\lambda _n)$, or using a matrix-like vertical notation

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda _1\\ \vdots \\ \lambda _n
\end{pmatrix}$$

However both notations represent the same vector $\mathbf{w}\in V$, but we choose some or other notation depending on the context to make things easier, by example if $M$ is an $n\times n$ matrix then we choose the vertical notation to represent the action of $M$ by the left to some vector, in this case

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
M_{1,1}&&\cdots &&M_{1,n}\\\vdots && &&\vdots \\M_{n,1}&&\cdots && M_{n,n}
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda _1\\ \vdots \\ \lambda _n
\end{pmatrix}
$$

However, to write the coordinates of $\mathbf{w}$ inside a text is preferable to use the notation $(\lambda _1,\ldots ,\lambda _n)$ instead. I hope you see it more clear now.

Comment: Would it be wrong to use the column and row notation at the same time?, because of course if $a=$(Column vector) and $a=$(Row vector) then $Ma ≠Ma$ Does this not make it kind of difficult to talk about the product of a matrix and euclidian vector because there is two possible interpretations?

Comment: if $a$ is a row vector then $Ma$ is not meaningful, that is, it doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

Given a vector space, V, over field F (typically R or C) we can define its "dual space", V*, as the set of all linear functions from V to F.  It can be shown that V and V* are isomorphic so V* is also a vector space.

In particlar, if V is finite dimensional, say dimension n, it is customary to represent each vector as a vertical n-column and each linear function as a horizontal n-row.  For example, if V is three dimensional we can write a vector as $v= \begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}$ and a linear function as $f= \begin{bmatrix}a & b & c \end{bmatrix}$.  Then the operation of function f on vector v can be written as a matrix product:
$f(v)= \begin{bmatrix}a & b & c \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a & b & c \end{bmatrix}= ax+ by+ cz$.

This is, of  course, just notation.

Comment: so in reality we can say that 'row and column' vectors are really just matrices, and we sort of 'represent' normal (euclidean or otherwise) vectors' with this notation, in truth the two forms of matrices cannot be equal but for the purposes of vector spaces we switch between the notation? We do this with the understanding we are in fact representing these vectors and as far as were concerned as long as the components are equal and the basis is the same we conclude they are the same (ignoring the notation choice).

Answer (score 0):

The answers above already well clarify that there is an isomorphism
between lists (n-uples), row vectors and column vectorsand thus the choice is a matter of convenience.

In linear algebra the column notation is more common because more conforming to the way we write
systems of linear equations.
Instead the row notation is common practice in Markov chains just because the matrix then looks tha same as
the usual representation of a transition matrix as row $\to$ column.

But interestingly, since you are studying physics, later on you will face with the important concept of
[co-variant and contra-variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_of_vectors) vectors,
dealing with which is useful to use both conventions together, while keeping  them distinct.

Comment: I think some of it is that I'm at an early stage of linear algebra where they use the tuple, vector, matrix rotational differences are ignored for simplicity.